# Arbitrary HTTP API Call to Enter Cell Value into a MUTL_PICKLIST Column

Tags: smartsheet-api

I am quite new new to Smartsheets and to programming.

I am using Integromat to update various stuff in Smartsheets - 99% operations are done via a nice interface for dummies.

But I have an issue with one column which is MULTI_PICKLIST and which cannot be processed with native dummy-friendly UI.

Basically, I'm adding a new row and one of the columns on the way is the MULTI_PICKLIST one. In order to enter value into this cell, I need to make an arbitrary HTTP API call.

I know row ID, I know column ID. I just need to construct the body of the HTTP request.

The possible picklist value are: John or Maya or Paul. Assume I need to enter "John" into the column.

Attached, you will find my "progress". I obviously, I'm stuck with the BODY part. Can someone give me a little push, please? I think it's gotta be like 5 lines of code.

This is what I have:
[image]

DZ

Comment: FYI I've appended an **update** to my initial answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things...

First, the value that you're using for **URL** doesn't look quite right. It should be in the following format, where `{sheetId}` is replaced with the ID of the sheet you're updating:

`sheets/{sheetId}/rows`

Second, I don't think you need the key/value that you've specified for **Query String** -- I'd suggest that you delete this info.

Next, I'm not sure what the other possible values are for **Type** (based on your screenshot, it looks like a picklist) -- but if `JSON` is an option, I'd suggest choosing that option instead of `Text`.

Finally, here's any example of the correct structure/contents for **Body** to update a MULTI_PICKLIST cell with the value `John` -- replace the value of the `id` property (5225480965908356) with your Row ID and replace the value of the `columnId` property (8436269809198980) with your Column ID:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5225480965908356", 
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": "8436269809198980", 
                "objectValue": {
                    "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
                    "values": ["John"]
                }
            }
            
        ]
    }
]
```

If you want to select multiple values for a MULTI_PICKLIST cell, here's an example that specifies two values for the cell (`John` and `Maya`):

```
[
    {
        "id": "5225480965908356", 
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": "8436269809198980", 
                "objectValue": {
                    "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
                    "values": ["John", "Maya"]
                }
            }
            
        ]
    }
]
```

** **UPDATE** **

My initial answer answer above assumed you wanted to *update* a cell value in a MULTI-PICKLIST column (b/c you've selected `PUT` for the **Method** value in your screenshot -- which is the verb used to update a row). Having re-read your question just now though, it sounds like maybe you want to **add** a new row...is that correct? If so, then the value for **Method** should be `POST` (not PUT), and **Body** will need to include additional objects within the `cells` array to specify values of other cells in the new row. The following example request (when used with the verb `POST`) adds a new row and populates 3 cells in that row, the first of which is a MULTI_PICKLIST cell:

```
[
    {
        "cells": [
            {
                "columnId": "8436269809198980", 
                "objectValue": {
                    "objectType": "MULTI_PICKLIST",
                    "values": ["John"]
                }
            },
            {
                "columnId": 6101753539127172,
                "value": "test value"
            },
            {
                "columnId": 4055216160040836,
                "value": 10
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

More info about the **Add Rows** request can be found in the Smartsheet API docs: [Add Rows](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?shell#add-rows).

Comment: Thanks, spot on! 

Everything works now :)

Comment: Excellent -- happy to help.